# Ability to drag between two datagrid item

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two datagridview in the same form.
Is there a way to drag items between them?
Can the drag update the DB inside the data source?
Thanks

Comment: windows form, net framework 4 if that matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes You Can see this
[C# Datagridview Drag & Drop](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/305c235e-761d-4f2c-83ba-23d8795a7b16/)

Comment: That seems to ask about dragging rows within a single DataGridView.  Not sure how it help with this situation.